# How to get the average time in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want get the the average time **between start-time and end-time and Where CUR-Time GroupBY user-name** i written the sql in laravel it's showing some error i can't find what's that because i'm new to that laravel please help to fix this sql error i submit the my sql and the error message.

```
 $avagTime = DB::table( 'active_user' )
            ->select(DB::raw('AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(acu_et) - TIME_TO_SEC(acu_at))'))
            ->where (DATE('acu_at') == ('CURDATE()'))
            ->get();[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: share your table structure

Comment: I attached the database structure

Comment: try this.... `->where (DATE('acu_at'),  ('CURDATE()'))`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'am2019-02-23T06:26:14+00:00000000_am28' in 'where clause' (SQL: select AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(acu_et) - TIME_TO_SEC(acu_at)) from `active_user` where `am2019-02-23T06:26:14+00:00000000_am28` = CURDATE())

Comment: what is the output of `'CURDATE()'`?

Comment: Today Date right

Comment: i tried like this 
$avagTime = DB::table( 'active_user' )
            ->select(DB::raw('AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`acu_at`,`acu_et`))'))
            ->where (DATE('acu_at') >= Carbon::today())
            ->get();

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188918/discussion-between-jerad-and-inzamam-idrees).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `where` clause. Laravel's query builder has a [whereDate()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) method that would be perfect for this:

```
$avagTime = DB::table('active_user')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(acu_et) - TIME_TO_SEC(acu_at))')
    ->whereDate('acu_at', today())
    ->get();
```

---

**NB** If you wanted to pass the where cause as a raw query (like you have in your example) you would need to use something like [whereRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-expressions) instead or `where()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** this code:

```
$currentTime = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

$avagTime = DB::table( 'active_user' )
          ->select(DB::raw('AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(acu_et) - TIME_TO_SEC(acu_at))'))
          ->where ('acu_at', $currentTime)
          ->get();
```

I think it would be helful. Thanks

Comment: You want to get the average between two dates?

Comment: and i want to pass the value to the chart

 $chart = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
            ->title('Total Clients Average Using Time')
            ->elementLabel("Total")
            ->values($avagTime->averageTime)
            ->responsive(true);

Comment: hey, If I do without query using DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to take the logic out of there? I prefer to just fetch date times from DB and using Carbon to convert them to  `Unix timestamp`. Then use them as they are simple int.