# Calculate average of waiting time for all orders Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to calculate the average of waiting time for all the order in de db.

To calculate waiting time i use this calculation

`$order->updated_at->diffInMinutes($order->created_at)`

But now i want to calculate this for all the orders together and divide it by the amount of orders in db

Comment: Bad way : you can loop over all your orders, sum the average and divide by the count of orders/ Good way : do it using a mysql query (for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838709/how-to-get-the-average-time-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would work:

```
$averageTime = Order::select(\DB::raw('AVG(created_at) as average_time'))->get();
```